# Location alias on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a configuration on NginX that sets the file path to a file like this:

```
location = /upload.php {
    alias /full/path/to/your/magentoproject/http/upload.php;
}
```

How can I do the same on Apache server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your apache virtualhost configuration add the line

```
alias "/upload.php" "/full/path/to/your/magentoproject/http/upload.php"
```

and restart the service.